# Have truces for the duration of Ramadan ever been customary/mandatory?

Tags: warfare, islam, religious-history

I know that you are exempt from fasting during Ramadan if a war is on (and also for other various reasons). But - has it ever been customary (or even - required) for Muslim fighting forces to offer truces, or to refrain from going on the offensive, during the month of Ramadan?

Comment: The opposition in Syria called for one http://uk.reuters.com/article/us-mideast-crisis-syria-truce-idUKKCN0YN4X3

Comment: @SleepingGod: Yes, I know, but 1. That's not a custom or a requirement, it was a suggestion (and quite possibly a "you wouldn't hit a man with glasses" kind of suggestion) 2. They didn't unilateraly refrain from attacks AFAICR 3. That's more of a current event than history...

Comment: I don't think so. The first battle fought by Muslims (Badr) was fought in Ramzan. There is no obligation on the Muslims to offer truces just because its Ramzan. Nor have I ever read on it being a custom, there have been various wars fought by Muslims against other Muslims and non-Muslims in month of Ramzan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there has been no such obligation or custom. Muslims have fought plenty of wars against each others and non-Muslims in the month of Ramadan without any considerations of offering a truce just because it's that month.

#### Muslim vs Muslims

1. Caliph [Ali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali) was murdered by a [Kharjite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd-al-Rahman_ibn_Muljam) on 21st of Ramadan. Granted it was act of one team instead of a proper battle but it is a part of the [First Fitna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Fitna) (First Muslim civil war) and War against [Kharjites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kharijite). The first Fitna itself raged for years without any regard for Ramadan. Case of other Muslim civil wars is similar.

#### Muslims vs Non-Muslims

1. The first battle of Islam, [Badr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Badr) was fought on 17th Ramadan, 2 AH.
2. [Second expedition of Wadi al-Qura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Expedition_of_Wadi_al-Qura) was fought in Ramadan of 6 AH.
3. [Mecca was conquered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conquest_of_Mecca) by Muslims on 20th Ramadan 8 AH.
4. Muslims won the decisive [battle of Guadalete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Guadalete) on 28-29th of Ramadan 92 AH.
5. Muslims finally stopped [the Mongol tide at Ain Jalut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Ain_Jalut) on 26th of Ramadan 658 AH.

#### Conclusion

No there is no instance of Muslims offering a truce just because the arising conflict happens to coincide with Ramadan. There is no provision for it in Muslim theology nor in their history.

Comment: +1 and accept, but the 1973 Ramadan war was not started by religious regimes - it was started by an attack by Egypt and Syria, the latter with quite a secular regime and the former under a "semi-secular" military dictatorship I guess you could say. Even though their populations are mostly Sunni Muslim of course.

Comment: @einpoklum Aha. I thought we were talking about Muslim forces regardless to the political structure of their states. That's why I thought I should probably mention YK war.

Comment: Well, a secular regime would not feel bound by religious customs, so the fact that it doesn't engender/offer a Ramadan truce is not evident to such a custom not existing. But you gave enough examples without that one...

Comment: @einpoklum Fair enough. I have removed the reference to YK war.